# Java JDIC error message

Tags: java, message, jdic

I have the following line in my Java app, and it's causing the following error message :

```
  WebBrowser webBrowser=new WebBrowser();


org.jdesktop.jdic.init.JdicInitException: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at org.jdesktop.jdic.init.JdicManager.initBrowserNative(Unknown Source)
        at org.jdesktop.jdic.browser.WebBrowser.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

The app still works, but I wonder if there is a way to correct the error ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem initializing jdic's native browser but it isn't obvious what it is.

Does passing a URL to the constructor help?

```
URL        url        = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
```

One more thing to check - do you have a default browser? If so, when you double click on an html file in a file manager does the browser window open? If this doesn't work then perhaps jdic is complaining about your default browser path.

Comment: No, the url didn't help, still the same error message. When I double clicked on an html file, my Firefox opened the file. I also have IE on my Vista PC.

Comment: jdic supports IE and Mozilla only. Mozilla is not the same as Firefox even though they are both produced by the same organization. Firefox is not supported. Here are some useful links:
https://jdic.dev.java.net/
https://jdic.dev.java.net/documentation/faq.html
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=262453

If you set your default browser to IE, do you still see the error?

Comment: One more possibility, could it be using IPv6 instead of IPv4?
    http://tivocommunity.com/tivo-vb/showthread.php?t=418580

Comment: I changed my default browser to IE, still got the same error message.